# How to get statemachineARN with name of statemachine

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-step-functions

I have a state machine name(e.g. custom-state-machine), and I want the statemachineARN of this, how could I achieve that.

there is function, list_state_machines(), but it gives all the state machines details.
Also, I saw the function describe_state_machine(), but it requires the statemachineARN.

My goal is to get statemachineARN just from the name of state-machine

Comment: Step Function ARNs follow a non-opaque pattern that includes the region, account and name: `arn:aws:states:us-east-1:012345789012:stateMachine:custom-state-machine`

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach. Get a list of all step functions using the list_state_machine call, then iterate through each, if there is a match on the name then extract the ARN.

```py
import boto3

name = 'HelloWorld'

sfn_arn = None

client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
response = client.list_state_machines()['stateMachines']
for sfn in response:
    if sfn['name'] == name:
        sfn_arn = sfn['stateMachineArn']
```